# Appending URL to output file with wget

Tags: wget, batch-processing

I'm using wget to read a batch of urls from an input file and download everything to a single output file, and I'd like to append each url before its downloaded content, anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: please show the code which you are using so far so we cann add the needed code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik wget does not directly support the use case you are envisioning. however, using standard  tools, you can emulate this feature.

we will proceed as follows:

- call `wget` with logging enabled
- let `sed` process the log executing the script detailed below
- execute the transformation result as a shell/batch script

conventions: use the following filenames:

- `wgetin.txt`:      the file with the urls to fetch using wget
- `wgetout.sed`:     sed script
- `wgetout.final`:   the final result
- `wgetass.sh/.cmd`: shell/batch script to assemble the downloaded files weaving in the url data
- `wget.log`:      the log file of the wget call

### Linux

the sed script (linux):

```
# delete lines _not_ matching the regex
/^\(Saving to: .\|--[0-9: \-]\+--  \)/! { d; }

# turn remaining content into something else
s/^--[0-9: \-]\+--  \(.*\)$/echo '\1\n' >>wgetout.final/
s/^Saving to: .\(.*\).$/cat '\1' >>wgetout.final/
```

the command line (linux):

```
rm wgetout.final | rm wgetass.sh | wget -i wgetin.txt -o wget.log | sed -f wgetout.sed -r  wget.log >wgetass.sh | chmod 755 wgetass.sh | ./wgetass.sh
```

### Windows

the syntax for windows batch scripts is slightly different. of course, the windows ports of wget and sed have to be installed first.

the sed script (windows):

```
# delete lines _not_ matching the regex
/^\(Saving to: .\|--[0-9: \-]\+--  \)/! { d; }

# turn remaining content into something else
s/^--[0-9: \-]\+--  \(.*\)$/echo "\1" >>wgetout.final/
s/^Saving to: .\(.*\).$/type "\1" >>wgetout.final/
```

the command line (windows):

```
del wgetout.final && del wgetass.cmd && wget -i wgetin.txt -o wget.log && sed -f wgetout.sed -r  wget.log >wgetass.cmd && wgetass.cmd
```